# Create an instance of a class with arbitrary arguments in Python?

Tags: python, class, instance

I want to write a function that will create an instance of whatever class is specified in one argument, and will call that class with an arbitrary number of arguments.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
def spawn(tospawn, *args):
    global current_state
    current_state.instance.append(globals()[tospawn](*args))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Guys I'm an idiot. The reason for making this function is so that classes that don't have access to other classes can still create instances of them, but they actually do have access to the other classes. So never mind.

Comment: Have you tried `tospawn(*args)`? Or is `tospawn` a string?

Comment: "This doesn't seem to work" - elaborate. What error do you get? What's the exact text of the error?

Comment: Tospawn is a string, but there will be a class of the same name. Here is the error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'instance'

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d=None):
        print a, b, c, d

args, kwargs = [1,2], {'c':3, 'd':4}
tospawn = MyClass

tospawn(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch the class out of globals; `tospawn` is a type, not a string.  Types are first class objects and you can just use them directly.

As for the entire code, I would do this with a classmethod instead personally.

```
class Spawner:
    __spawned__ = []

    @classmethod
    def spawn(cls, tospawn, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = tospawn(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.__spawned__.append(obj)

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print args

Spawner.spawn(TestClass, "these", "are", "args")
print Spawner.__spawned__
```

Answer (score 0):

`globals()` returns a dictionary with string keys. Something like

```
    from collection import deque

    args = range(20), 3
    a = globals()['deque'](*args)
```

will work, but the following will give a key error

```
    a = globals()[deque](*args)
```

because deque is a type and not a string.

Maybe you can do something like:

```
def spawn(tospawn, *args):
    global current_state
    try:
        current_state.instance.append(globals()[tospawn](*args))
    except KeyError:
        current_state.instance.append(tospawn(*args))
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because I'm passing that function a string (with the same name as a class) as the first argument. If I do tospawn(*args), it looks for a class named tospawn, rather than a class with the same name as the value of tospawn.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `eval`?

```
def spawn(tospawn, *args):
     global current_state
     current_state.instance.append(eval("{}(*{})".format(tospawn, args)))
```